# What's wrong with this sscanf() format string?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to parse a simple string: a character from the set "rgbcmyw" followed by a character form the set "slh" then an integer.

```
risk:9008:~$ cat test-scanf.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char c,m;
    int s;

    printf("Scanned %d elements.\n", sscanf(argv[1], "%[rgbcmyw]%[slh]%d", &c, &m, &s));
    printf("Scanned:\n\tc = %c (%d)\n\tm = %c (%d)\n\ts = %d\n",c,c,m,m,s);

    return 0;
}
risk:9012:~$ gcc test-scanf.c && ./a.out rs40
Scanned 3 elements.
Scanned:
    c =  (0)
    m = s (115)
    s = 40
risk:9013:~$
```

**Why is zero being assigned to 'c'?**

**EDIT: The solution**

One needs space for the character being scanned *plus* a `nul` termination:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char c[2],m[2]; /* Need space for the character *and* the 'nul' termination. */
    int s;

    printf("Scanned %d elements.\n", sscanf(argv[1], "%[rgbcmyw]%[slh]%d", c, m, &s));
    printf("Scanned:\n\tc = %s\n\tm = %s\n\ts = %d\n",c,m,s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With `%s` or `%[]` you should generally include a field width to prevent it from reading more characters than you have room for (size of the array minus 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is passing the wrong type of parameters to `sscanf()`. The "`%[]` specifier expects a `char *` pointer.

Comment: So, the declaration should be `char c[1], m[1];`?

Comment: And you would need to remove the `&` from the parameter.

Comment: Tried it.  Didn't work.  Removed the `&` and then added `*` in the `printf()`.

Comment: Oh ... the array's need space for a `nul` terminator.  The scanning was overwriting the first scan.

Comment: The `%[…]` scan set operator also adds a null terminator; the declarations should be `char c[2], m[2];` — and the zero in `c` was (probably) because the null terminator after `&m` in the question overwrote `c`.

Comment: The `%[...]` can also read several consecutive characters from the set, so if he wants only a single `char` (plus the null) he'll need to specify a field width of 1.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `string` conversion specifier and a `char` pointer. `%[foo]` expects a pointer to `char` (and there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, plus a terminating null byte), not simply a pointer to a `char`.

Comment: Pointer to a string doesn't exist. Specifier [] requires a pointer to an initial element of a character array of sufficient size(doesn't have to be null terminated), i.e. a pointer to a char: `char*`

Comment: Thank you - fixed.

Comment: `expects a pointer to a char *, not pointer to a char.` What do you mean by that? Pointer to a `char*` is `char**`, scanf specifier `[]` requires a pointer to a char, which is `char*`.

Comment: Not "a pointer to a `char *`", just "a `char *`"... it's just that the `char *` needs to point to more than a single `char` since it will be used for a null terminated string (which might hold more than one matching character, plus the null).

Comment: OK, one more time, a pointer to an *array of char*, not a pointer to *char \**, agreed.

Comment: That is also not correct, a pointer to an array or char, is: `char(*)[]`, specifier `[]` requires a pointer to a char: `char*`.